# How to find the largest integer (n), such that n^3 < 12,000, using a while loop

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, while-loop, integer

This is what I have so far. The idea is it's supposed to increase n until n^3 is less than 12000, and print out n at the highest integer below 12k.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 0;
    int nCubed = (int) (Math.pow(n, 3));

    while (nCubed < 12000) {
        n++;
    }
    System.out.println("The highest integer below 12000 is " +n);
 }

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `n*n*n` instead of `(int)(Math.pow(n,3))`. `Math.pow` is good for floating point computations (although I'd use `n*n` instead of `Math.pow(n,2)` even for a float) but it's suboptimal for integers unless you expect integer overflow, in which case casting back to an `int` is not a good idea. (Obviously in this case, integer overflow is not going to happen.)

Comment: Is there no mathematical solution to this? It sounds like there should be.
For example. there are only 22 integer cubed numbers below 12000. So it would be quicker to keep an array of all the cubes, and just iterate through them checking if they are below your taget, than calculating the cube every time.

Comment: The mathematical solution is: `int n = (int) Math.pow(12000, 1.0/3);` but to fix your looping solution you need to update nCubed inside the loop (it is currently always 0 and your loop will not terminate.)

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the nCubed value each time in the loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 0;
    int nCubed = (int) (Math.pow(n, 3));

    while (nCubed < 12000) {
        n++;
        nCubed = (int) (Math.pow(n, 3));
    }
    System.out.println("The highest integer below 12000 is " +(n-1));
 }
```

Comment: And please notice that this answer correctly prints (n-1) since the n you have found is the first integer such that n^3 is LARGER than 12,000.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class newClass{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int largestValue=0;
    int n=0;

while(Math.pow(n,3)<12000) {
     if(n>largestValue)
         largestValue=n;
n++;

}
System.out.println(largestValue);


}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please take the [tour] and have a read of [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Providing additional context and descriptions make answers more useful to a wider audience.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Loops_13
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      int n = 0;
      while (Math.pow(n,3) < 12000)
      {
         if (Math.pow(n + 1,3) >= 12000)
            break;
         n++;
      }
      System.out.println("The largest integer n such that n^3 is less than 12,000 is " + n);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Find the largest n

public class Pb5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n=0;
     while(true) {
        if(n*n*n<12000) {
            n++;
        }
        else
            break;
      }
     System.out.println("The largest integer n less than 12000 is:: "+(n-1));
    }

}
```